# How to access my model from my view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I cannot seem to figure out how to access my Model from my View.  I am confused.

Here is my Home controller.  I have verified that "specimens" is being populated with data from the database:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    wildtropEntities wildlifeDB = new wildtropEntities();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["CurrentDate"] = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

        var specimens = from s in wildlifeDB.specimen1
                        select s;

        return View(specimens);
    }

}
```

And here are couple snippets from my View:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<% foreach (WildlifeTropical.Models.specimen s in ??????)
    { %>
     <div>s.Name</div>
 <% } %>
```

I assumed I would be able to access "specimens" since I passed it to the View from the Controller (ie, return View(specimens))...but it isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to make your view strongly typed to a collection of `specimen` which is what you are passing to it from your controller action (`IEnumerable<specimen>`):

```
<%@ Page 
    Language="C#" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<WildlifeTropical.Models.specimen>>" %>

<% foreach (WildlifeTropical.Models.specimen s Model) { %>
     <div><%= Html.Encode(s.Name) %></div>
<% } %>
```

Notice how the view inherits `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<WildlifeTropical.Models.specimen>>` and it is now strongly typed to a collection of `specimens` that you will be able to loop through.

This being said, personally I don't like writing foreach loops in my views. They make them look ugly. In this case I would use a display template:

```
<%@ Page 
    Language="C#" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<WildlifeTropical.Models.specimen>>" %>
<%= Html.DisplayForModel() %>
```

and then I would define a display template which will automatically be rendered for each element of the model collection (`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/specimen.ascx`):

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<WildlifeTropical.Models.specimen>" %>
<div>
    <%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name) %>
</div>
```

See how the `specimen.ascx` user control is now strongly typed to `System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<WildlifeTropical.Models.specimen>`. This is because it will be rendered for each specimen of the main view model.

Comment: thank you very much.  i tried implementing the first block of code you provided (figured i would move on the next parts after i get the first part working).  when i debug, i do not end up with a list of the names being displayed...instead i literally get s.Name, s.Name, etc, etc.  What could be wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user1125648, yes, that's because I did a typo in my answer. You should use: `<div><%= Html.Encode(s.Name) %></div>`. I have updated my answer to fix this.

Comment: i figured it out...i was missing <%= %> tags.  shoot me now.

Comment: thank you, darin.  i didn't see your response before i entered mine.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about MVC2. In MVC 3(with Razor View Engine), I can pass the Model / ViewModel to the View like this.

```
@model MyProject.ViewModel.UserViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Welcome To My Site";
}
<div class="divSubHead">
<h2>Hello @Model.FirstName</h2></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Note the Inherits for the Page.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of IEnumerable(Of Specimen))" %>

<% foreach (WildlifeTropical.Models.specimen s in Model)
     { %>
     <div>s.Name</div>
 <% } %>
```